# Musaf for Rosh Chodesh

Tags: tefilla

During Chol Hamoed we recite the same Musaf Amidah as we recite on Yom Tov itself - i.e. Ata V'chartanu... Why do we recite a different Musaf Amidah when Rosh Chodesh coincides with Shabbat - Ata Yatzarta - from the Musaf we say when it falls during the week - Rashei Chodashim?

Comment: Chol Hamoed and Yom Tov are both parts of the same holiday. Not relevant. What you should point out is we say the same holiday musaf even on Shabbat of the holiday

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Geoffrey and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!